# SSRS Reorder columns based on parameter

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters

I have a report that I want to share between multiple clients. However, each client wants different columns. So based on one of the report parameters, for certain values I hide the columns that client isn't interested in.

However, some clients also want the columns in a different order. Is it possible to use a report parameter to re-order the columns?

**One solution**

Say Client 1 wants columns `A | B` in that order, but Client 2 wants them as `B | A`.

1. Create columns `A | B | A` (duplicate `A`)
2. If Client 1 is selected, hide the second `A`
3. If Client 2 is selected, hide the first `A`.

**end**

I *don't* want to use the above solution because we could end up having 30 different column orderings.

So, is there another, easier way to re-order columns based on a report parameter, or would I be better off sharing the DataSet and creating different reports (`.rdl`s) per client?

Comment: Do all your fields share the same data type, formatting and length?

Comment: All my fields? You mean the same field between clients? Yes. Otherwise I'd add a new column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go down the path of using Switch functions in every detail cell to pick the field based on a parameter. I wouldn't. I did it once for an insistent client and regretted it every since - maintenance and debugging is a nightmare.

It's just a limitation of SSRS.  I would build a series of tables and conditionally hide them based on the parameter.

Comment: okay, i assumed it was a limitation, but I couldn't find any definitive answers saying that there wasn't an easy way to do this. thanks.